# Getting a "Cannot find reference 'foo' in 'bar'" error in Pycharm + pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am using Pycharm to run automation framwork built with Pytest.
In some fixtures that are trying to acceess attribute of other fixtures, I am gettings:
Cannot find reference 'foo' in 'bar' error.

Example:

In my fixtures.py file I have the following:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def foo():
    foo.bar = Baz()
    yield foo

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def play(foo, request):
    foo.bar.do_something(request.param)
    yield
```

In this case, Pycharm will mark `bar` in `play` with an orange underline, and it will say:
`Cannot find reference 'bar' in 'function'`.

Also, upon cmd+clicking `foo` or `bar`, it will not take me to the function deceletaion of `foo`, but cmd+clicking `do_something` will indded take me to the decleration of `do_something` in `Baz`.

Simply ignoring this error is not something I can consider.

I expected Pycharm to "know" the attribute I added to each fixture and to be able to refer me to it's decleration.

Comment: Have you tried: `def play(foo: Baz, request)` so that `play` can know the type of `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redefining `foo`, try this

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def foo():
    _foo = MagicMock()
    _foo.bar = Baz()
    yield _foo

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def play(foo, request):
    foo.bar.do_something(request.param)
    yield
```